# PostgreSQL ROW_NUMBER with timestamp conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to extend PARTITION BY to keep rows in same partition if ts_created of current row is within 1hour of previous row.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.user_email, 
       t1.ts_created,
       t1.prev_ts
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.user_email ORDER BY t1.ts_created DESC) AS time_order
FROM (SELECT id,
             user_email,
             ts_created,
             lag(ts_created) OVER(PARTITION BY user_email ORDER BY ts_created DESC) AS prev_ts
      FROM table1) AS t1 ORDER BY t1.ts_created DESC;
```

So far i'm doing partition over user_email and prepared timestamp of previous row, now i'm abit lost on how to handle time component between current and previous row.

expectation

| id | user_email | ts_created | time_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | mailA | 2022-01-01 07:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 5 | mailA | 2022-01-01 06:40:00.000 | 2 |
| 4 | mailA | 2022-01-01 05:50:00.000 | 3 |
| 3 | mailA | 2022-01-01 05:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 2 | mailA | 2022-01-01 03:50:00.000 | 1 |
| 1 | mailB | 2021-01-01 03:30:00.000 | 1 |

Comment: Use `lag` to determine if there is a gap or not, count gaps, partition by the count.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for pointing it out, that did the trick.